# How to create a declaration for an npm module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I can't figure out how to create a declaration for a specific npm module. Namely [bbcode-to-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bbcode-to-react).

The main file is indicated as index.js and has only a little code:

```
'use strict';

var _parser = require('./parser');

var _parser2 = _interopRequireDefault(_parser);

var _tag = require('./tag');

var _tag2 = _interopRequireDefault(_tag);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

module.exports = new _parser2.default();
module.exports.Parser = _parser2.default;
module.exports.Tag = _tag2.default;
```

Both './parser' and './tag' contain classes I need.

I can't figure out from the typescript docs, how to declare/export this set-up in the d.ts file. The best I can find related to module.exports is all about exporting a single class or function but I need both the Parser and Tag classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the typing to `bbcode-to-react`:

```
declare module 'bbcode-to-react' {
    import * as React from 'react';

    function toReact(input: string): JSX.Element;
    function registerTag(name: string, tag: typeof Tag): void;

    class Tag {
        name: string;
        parent: JSX.Element;
        text: string;
        params: { [index: string]: any };
        children: JSX.Element[];

        getComponents(): JSX.Element;
        getContent(raw?: boolean): string;
        toText(contentAsHTML?: boolean): string;
        toHTML(): string;
        toReact(): JSX.Element;
    }
}
```

put this code inside a `bbcode-to-react.d.ts` file.

> Make sure you have `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` installed

An example using this typing:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as parser from 'bbcode-to-react';
import { Tag } from 'bbcode-to-react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

const Example1 = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <p>{parser.toReact('[b]strong[/b]')}</p>
    );
}

console.log(renderToString(<Example1 />));

class YoutubeTag extends Tag {
    toReact() {
        const attributes = {
            src: this.getContent(true),
            width: this.params.width || 420,
            height: this.params.height || 315,
        };
        return (
            <iframe
                {...attributes}
                frameBorder="0"
                allowFullScreen
            />
        );
    }
}

class BoldTag extends Tag {
    toReact() {
        return (
            <b>{this.getComponents()}</b>
        );
    }
}

parser.registerTag('youtube', YoutubeTag);
parser.registerTag('b', BoldTag);

const Example2 = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <p>{parser.toReact('[youtube width="400"]https://www.youtube.com/embed/AB6RjNeDII0[/youtube]')}</p>
    );
}

console.log(renderToString(<Example2 />));
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't expecting someone to write it for me but now I can see it, I can see why it's set up this particular way.

Comment: I'm glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

A pull request just got merged on `DefinitelyTyped`. See [this link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/46891). Now anyone want to use typescript with `bbcode-to-react` module can easily do

```
npm install --dev @types/bbcode-to-react
```

for strong-typing.

You are also welcome to help contribute by opening more pull requests on `DefinitelyTyped`. Hope it can help.